# What text editor under OS X can close current window when you press ESC key?

Tags: text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor that can close the current file when you press `ESC` key.

I am interested about this for using with a file manager, I open for edit a file and with `ESC` I want to return to the file commander.

I tried to override the close window command on `XCode` but it didn't work, instead of closing the window it does write me an upside down question mark!?

In addition, I tried to assign `ESC` as shortcut key in System Preferences, but this is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

[Emacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html) allows you to override shortcuts keys.

Add this line to your *.emacs* file (located in your home directory) :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but only with Emacs. Maybe I will try to learn how to use emacs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any word processor can be made to close its front window when you hit `escape`. Write a little AppleScript, like this:

```
tell application "BBEdit" -- change this to the WP you want
    try
        close front window
    end try
end tell
```

Get a copy of 'FastScripts' script menu replacement,
and put your script in Library/Scripts/Applications/BBEdit folder.
Assign the escape key to the script (in FastScripts preferences).

Comment: It at my script!

Comment: --tell application "BBEdit"
--try
--close front window
--end try
--end tell
--return